# In ruby what is this type of definition: self.class.method

Tags: ruby, class, self

I am a NOOB trying to understand some code.

What does this self.class.current_section do?

```
class MyClass
  class << self  
    def current_section(*section)
      if section.empty?
        @current_section
      else
        @current_section = section[0]
      end
    end
  end


  def current_section()
    self.class.current_section
  end

  def current_section=(section)
    self.class.current_section(section)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It forwards the message (method call request) received by the object to the corresponding class.

Say you have a class

```
class MyClass
  def MyClass.current_section
    puts "I'm the class method."
  end

  def current_section
    self.class.current_section
  end
end

h = MyClass.new
h.current_section # outputs "I'm the class method."
```

Calling `h`'s method, it looks up `h`'s class (`MyClass`) and invokes the method `current_section` of that class.

So, by the definitions above, every object of the class `MyClass` has a method `current_section` which is routed to the central `current_section` of the class.

The definition of the class methods in your question is just using a different syntax for doing the same: adding a method to the class object.

Answer (score 3):

`self` returns the the current object.

`self.class` returns the class of current object.

`self.class.current_section` invokes the method of the class of current object (that method called `current_section`).

```
 def current_section()
    p self
    p self.class
 end

 current_section()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class << self  
    def current_section(*section)
      if section.empty?
        @current_section
      else
        @current_section = section[0]
      end
    end
end
```

This code part is being evaluated in the Class Object scope because of the `class << self` statement. Thus `current_section` is being defined as a class method, invokable as `Myclass.current_section.`

```
def current_section()
  self.class.current_section
end
```

This part is just the definition of an instance method, and thus `self` is an instance of the `Myclass` object.

`self.class` gets the class of such instance, thus, `Myclass`, and the current_section method of the class is invoked.